# fancontrol service not starting after rebooting open suse linux

Tags: opensuse

I switched to openSuse (Leap 42.2) from ubuntu.
When I using Ubuntu, I used lm_sensors and fancontrol because my cpu fan was not rotating a little. Those program ran programs without any issuue on Ubuntu.
Afeter switching to openSuse I had same problem mensioned above. So, I installed sensors(no lm-sensors in suse) program using following command

```
sudo zypper install sensors;
```

Then hit,

```
sudo sensors-detect;
```

and gave yes to all. Arter I ran

```
sudo pwmconfig;
```

command. My /etc/fancontrol configurations as follows,

```
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon1= hwmon2=
DEVNAME=hwmon1=acpitz hwmon2=dell_smm
FCTEMPS= hwmon2/pwm1=hwmon1/temp1_input
FCFANS= hwmon2/pwm1=hwmon2/fan1_input
MINTEMP= hwmon2/pwm1=35
MAXTEMP= hwmon2/pwm1=55
MINSTART= hwmon2/pwm1=90
MINSTOP= hwmon2/pwm1=255
MINPWM=hwmon2/pwm1=0
MAXPWM= hwmon2/pwm1=255
```

Then I hit,

```
sudo service fancontrol start;
```

Now my cpu fan is running well. Then I rebooted my pc. But, unfortunately my cpu fan is not running again automatically. I have to re-run pwmcofig command again. How can I solve this problem?

Note: I couldn'n found any openSuse commad equivalent to below commands available in UBUNTU:

```
sudo service module-init-tools restart;
sudo service kmod start;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open Yast, find there under system category "services-control", open that, find there (press f, than search between services, which names are beginning with f letter, so is easier) fancontrol service. There will be by you written inactive (dead). CHange bootmode to  "onboot", than press start service, dann accept, ok, exit yast. After next boot that service will restart automatically, when you configured pwm right and when the service will find config. file in directory, where you saved (default /etc/fancontrol).

I did like this on opensuse 15 leap and it started automatically today.

Answer (score 0):

MINSTOP= hwmon2/pwm1=255

Here you did mistake (I think), Here must be the value, in which fan stops. In command line you can during pwmconfig press t key and test that, find the right value. Not always that works, when your terminal will think very long and not display results, you can stop-exit it, retry all again and write with fingers for example value between 30-55. Reason is following: your fan must not stop, when your motherboard gives him instead min. (in fact max.) PWM value=255..And min. PWM value must be not more, as min start value of fan. And min stopp value < min start value.